# ReplaceAll works and does not work for the same expression

Tags: replacement, rule

I will give two cases, where the rule replacement works in the first one and does not work in the second one, but they are essentially the same!

Consider the following definition, whose details are not important:

```
vall = -Sqrt[Δ^2 + μ^2 + 2*μ*Sqrt[px^2 + py^2] + px^2 + py^2]
```

Now, we check the following:

```
vall /. {ϕ -> 0, py -> pyy, px -> 0, μ -> 0}
```

As expected, I can obtain the desired replacement:

[image: minus square root of pyy^2 + Delta^2: substitution achieved]

Now, consider the following expression, which contains the above expression as a subexpression:

```
Exists[
 {py, pyy}, 
 123 == (vall /. {ϕ -> 0, py -> pyy, px -> 0, μ -> 0}) == 0  ]
```

The result is surprising:

[image: no substitution was achieved]

As can be seen in the picture, no replacement `py -> pyy` is made!

Why does this happen?

Comment: You should condense your problem to a much smaller, minimal working example that reproduces the behavior you see.

Comment: @MarcoB I simplified the code.

Comment: After printing vars like Exists[{py, pyy}, Print[{py, pyy}]; 
 123 == (vall /. {\[Phi] -> 0, py -> pyy, px -> 0, \[Mu] -> 0}) == 0] your will note that Exists renamed vars. So, substitution simply do not mach pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that this has to do with the `HoldAll` attribute of `Exists` (see `Attributes[Exists]`). However, if you force evaluation of its second argument, i.e. the expression you are trying to modify, you obtain the desired result:

```
Exists[
  {py, pyy}, 
  Evaluate[ 123 == (vall /. {ϕ -> 0, py -> pyy, px -> 0, μ -> 0}) == 0 ]
]

(* Out: Exists[{pyy}, 123 == -Sqrt[pyy^2 + Δ^2] == 0] *)
```